# Fluent NHibernate Configuration invalid or incomplete - 3rd party types in mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to convert a ASP.NET Web API project over to use Fluent NHibernate. It's been awhile since I Hibernated. I have a mapping to a model which is composed of 3rd party types. For example:

```
public MyClass{
public MyClass{}

public virtual int Id {get;set;}
public virtual SpecialType {get;set;} //I don't own the 'SpecialType' class.

}
```

Then I have a simple mapping for this class:

```
public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Id(i => i.Id);
        Map(i => i.SpecialType);          

    }
}
```

I have the following Configuration:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
            .ConnectionString(_connString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClassMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(UpdateSchema)
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The configuration bombs and complains:

> Could not determine type for: mynamespace.SpecialType...,

'Potential Reasons' collection is empty in the exception detail. I suspect that this could be because of the 'SpecialType'. That type does override ToString().. I'm wondering if the problem is that NHibernate does not know how to set or get this property value? Are 3rd party types an issue with NHibernate? Do I need to provide the mapping with information about how to proxy this object?

Thanks!!

**Edit**

Looking through the source to 'SpecialType' I think I see what the problem is. This class has a private constructor. An instance of this class is created using method 'FromValue(string value)'. I think this must be why NHibernate is confused. There must be way to configure how the framework news up instances..

Comment: Have you tried building a mapping for the `SpecialType` class' properties? E.g. `Map(x => x.SpecialType.Prop1); Map(x => x.SpecialType.Prop2);` etc?

Comment: No.. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private parameterless constructors are fine for NHibernate. Just create a Mapping for it for example as component in MyClassMap:

```
Component(x => x.SpecialType, c => 
{
    c.Map(st => st.Prop1);
    c.Map(st => st.Prop2);
});
```